# Applications of circular linked lists

Tags: data-structures, linked-lists

Is a circular linked list just a nice programming exercise, or does it have any real world applications?  I am unable to find much information on this topic, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They are mostly a programming exrecise. But understanding them is certainly important to understand some other concepts (e.g graphs and cycles within graphs).

Comment: Not going to say that it’s the best solution, but long time ago I used them for multithreading implementation: we had threads, each thread had a priority, and we wanted to switch between the highest-priority threads. So it was natural to group threads by priority and use some kind of circular data structure for each group.